# ts_rank between two ts vector columns

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have two columns in two tables and I want to select the top 20% most relevant terms

```
Table A: items
id, 
title (string)

Table B: queries
id,
query (string)
```

Basically I want to find the top 20% comparing rank for **ts_vector(items.title)** and **ts_vector(queries.query)**

Comment: Maybe you can use `ts_rank_cd()` function. As described on documentation [Controlling Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html) on section **12.3.3. Ranking Search Results**. As described on documentation, this rank creates a normalization

Comment: Ok, can you write me an example of the query? I tried it but It didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ts_rank_cd(tsquery, tsvector, int)` to get text proximity. I created two tables `a` and `b` with your columns and put information on that. The ts_rank_cd function receives a factor to normalize, in the documentation, `32` is the value to normalize between `0` and `1`. It's not considered a index on `0%` to `100%` but it's considered a good factor of proximity as explained in [text search controls](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html).

Table a:

```
postgres=# select * from a;
 id |       title        
----+--------------------
  1 | a rat and a cat
  2 | a cat and a mouse
  3 | a tiger or a rhino
(3 rows)
```

Table b:

```
postgres=# select * from b;
 id |      query      
----+-----------------
  4 | lorem ipsum
  3 | lorem cat
  2 | mouse rhino
  1 | a rat and a cat
  5 | rat fat cat
(5 rows)
```

The comparison needs to be executed whith `ts_rank_cd(tsvector, tsquery)` so, we convert the first `a.title` to  `tsvector` and `b.query` to `tsquery` and make a comparison.

```
postgres=# select ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(title), query, 32) as rank, 
                  title,
                  query 
             from a, 
                  (select plainto_tsquery('english', query) as query,
                          id
                     from b
                  ) AS b ORDER BY rank DESC; 

   rank    |       title        |         query         
-----------+--------------------+-----------------------
 0.0322581 | a rat and a cat    | 'rat' & 'cat'
         0 | a rat and a cat    | 'lorem' & 'cat'
         0 | a rat and a cat    | 'mous' & 'rhino'
         0 | a rat and a cat    | 'rat' & 'fat' & 'cat'
         0 | a cat and a mouse  | 'lorem' & 'ipsum'
         0 | a cat and a mouse  | 'lorem' & 'cat'
         0 | a cat and a mouse  | 'mous' & 'rhino'
         0 | a cat and a mouse  | 'rat' & 'cat'
         0 | a cat and a mouse  | 'rat' & 'fat' & 'cat'
         0 | a tiger or a rhino | 'lorem' & 'ipsum'
         0 | a tiger or a rhino | 'lorem' & 'cat'
         0 | a tiger or a rhino | 'mous' & 'rhino'
         0 | a tiger or a rhino | 'rat' & 'cat'
         0 | a rat and a cat    | 'lorem' & 'ipsum'
         0 | a tiger or a rhino | 'rat' & 'fat' & 'cat'
(15 rows)
```

If you want to get a more "relaxed" result, you can substitute the `&` by `|`, just making a replace.

```
postgres=# select ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(title), replace(query::text, '&', '|')::tsquery, 32) as rank, 
                 title::tsvector,
                 replace(query::text, '&', '|')::tsquery from a, (select 
                 plainto_tsquery('english', query) as query, id from b) AS  b ORDER BY rank DESC; 
   rank    |          title           |        replace        
-----------+--------------------------+-----------------------
  0.166667 | 'a' 'and' 'cat' 'rat'    | 'rat' | 'cat'
  0.166667 | 'a' 'and' 'cat' 'rat'    | 'rat' | 'fat' | 'cat'
 0.0909091 | 'a' 'or' 'rhino' 'tiger' | 'mous' | 'rhino'
 0.0909091 | 'a' 'and' 'cat' 'rat'    | 'lorem' | 'cat'
 0.0909091 | 'a' 'and' 'cat' 'mouse'  | 'lorem' | 'cat'
 0.0909091 | 'a' 'and' 'cat' 'mouse'  | 'rat' | 'cat'
 0.0909091 | 'a' 'and' 'cat' 'mouse'  | 'mous' | 'rhino'
 0.0909091 | 'a' 'and' 'cat' 'mouse'  | 'rat' | 'fat' | 'cat'
         0 | 'a' 'or' 'rhino' 'tiger' | 'rat' | 'fat' | 'cat'
         0 | 'a' 'and' 'cat' 'rat'    | 'mous' | 'rhino'
         0 | 'a' 'and' 'cat' 'mouse'  | 'lorem' | 'ipsum'
         0 | 'a' 'or' 'rhino' 'tiger' | 'lorem' | 'ipsum'
         0 | 'a' 'or' 'rhino' 'tiger' | 'lorem' | 'cat'
         0 | 'a' 'or' 'rhino' 'tiger' | 'rat' | 'cat'
         0 | 'a' 'and' 'cat' 'rat'    | 'lorem' | 'ipsum'
(15 rows)
```